# How can the decision threshold in this multi-class SVC model be adjusted to balance sensitivity and specificity?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, svm

Like the title reads, I have a multi-classs SVC model that I coded on python using sklearn that's doing its best effort to categorize 4 known groups. Briefly, the purpose of this model is to attempt and diagnose mental disorders using specific numerical parameters extracted from brain scans. This is a simplified version of my model:

```
# Data load
brain_data_path = '/content/All_Brain_Data_nonNA.csv'
brain_data = pd.read_csv(brain_data_path)
patient_features = brain_data.iloc[:,1:]
patient_groups = brain_data.iloc[:,0]
# Preprocessing
scaler = StandardScaler()
patient_features_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(patient_features)
# Feature selection
threshold_of_feature_count = 134
SVC_model = SVC(kernel='linear', probability=True, random_state=42, break_ties=True).fit(patient_features_scaled, patient_groups)
FT_selection = SelectFromModel(SVC_model, threshold=-np.inf, max_features= threshold_of_feature_count)
Features_of_importance = FT_selection.transform(patient_features_scaled)
# Crossvalidation
KfoldCross = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True)
prediction_scores = np.empty_like(patient_groups)
# Model
for kf, chng in KfoldCross.split(Features_of_importance, patient_groups):
  model = SVC(kernel='linear', break_ties=True, class_weight= 'balanced').fit(Features_of_importance[kf], patient_groups[kf])
  prediction_scores[chng] = model.predict(Features_of_importance[chng])
X = np.where(patient_groups == prediction_scores, 1, 0)
```

After adjusting hyper parameters and every setting that can be possibly fine tuned, this is the outcome:

```
Macro-recall:  0.6750946326069478
F1-score:  0.6766330169765499
Precision:  0.6865484710474951

Group 1 - Sensitivity: 0.7307692307692307, Specificity: 0.9047619047619048, ROC: 0.8177655677655677

Group 2 - Sensitivity: 0.5185185185185185, Specificity: 0.9423076923076923, ROC: 0.7304131054131053

Group 3 - Sensitivity: 0.6551724137931034, Specificity: 0.9019607843137255, ROC: 0.7785665990534144

Group 4 - Sensitivity: 0.7959183673469388, Specificity: 0.8292682926829268, ROC: 0.8125933300149327
```

Things seem good, but Group 2 and 3 could use some love. One thing I noticed was the very high specificity and relatively low sensitivity. Meaning the model is acting fairly conservative by predicting negatives more accurately than positives.

My theory is that by editing the decision threshold of the SVC, I might be able to balance the sensitivity and specificity improving total performance. However, it seems that while this can be done for binary problems, there's no simple way to achieve this task in a multi-class system.

I would greatly appreciate any help you could provide in balancing these scores.

Answer (score 0):

Two alternatives are:

- Set `class_weight='balanced'`. This will penalise the model equally for the positive and negative cases, and may improve your sensitivity if it's due to the positive class being relatively rare compared to the negative class.
- As a secondary option - the `.fit` method takes am optional `sample_weight=` parameter. If there are regions of the brain or specific points that are being missed and contributing to low sensitivity, you can assign them higher weights to put more emphasis on them.

These relatively simple adjustments may help boost sensitivity.